# Creating a 'stable' release from a SVN repo

Tags: svn, git, release-management

I got several developers who are working on a project and committing into /trunk

In an ideal world, their code would be bug free and they would of completed all parts of a problem before committing, but as we know that is not always the case.

Often I will go through and only update the files which I know are good, then test and release a public build but it's getting harder and harder - with SVN when you update a file it's ALL or nothing, unless you want to start adding in the edits by hand to files - annoying.

So I need a way, of taking the code, and getting a more fine grained approach to pulling in their changes - (almost like the UI of git add --patch), I can then go through each change set (down to the line) and add things which work then release build. (tagging this would be ideal).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is what branches are for.

If trunk is what should be the stable branch, then you could have each developer work in their own branch. You then merge specific changes from those branches into trunk. When you're ready to do a release you can create a tagged branch from trunk.

Alternatively you could use trunk as the unstable dev branch that everyone commits into, and merge specific updates from that into a stable release branch.

Comment: This sounds like what I am thinking, but in order to merge specific changes I will need to use something like git/mercurial? With that, can I see the entire differences between two branches and only pull in changes I want (down to sections of a file)?

Comment: Subversion provides everything you need to do merging. I don't think you can restrict this to specific portions of a file though. The idea is that you merge specific sets of revisions. e.g. if a dev has committed a new feature in revs 123-127, you merge that range into your stable branch.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use short iterations.
2. insist that a set of unit tests pass on every check-in
3. insist that a set of smoke tests pass on the trunk every night
4. show the door to people who won't cooperate
5. if you can't get people to split projects into small, testable, non-regressive changes, banish them to branches and keep them off the trunk.
6. use jenkins or hudson or whatever to help enforce

In short, you can't fix your process with source control. If you want to try, svn is not your friend for the process you are approximately describing.

Comment: Thanks, and while that is mostly true there would still be times when they started implementing features and commit things which we don't need to ship yet - so there is all sorts of reasons just wonder whats best.